# What are the concurrency guarantees for Flowable.merge()

Tags: rx-java2, reactivex

I've looked in details into the documentation of RxJava's `Flowable.merge()` operator, but I can't find the information I need.

My understanding, after some experimentation, is that given `n` upstream flowables *F<sub>i</sub>* that are each emitting values in their own thread *T<sub>i</sub>*, the `merge` operator guarantees that the merged flowable emits those values in a serialized fashion, such that the downstream has observed it before emitting the previous one. Experimentation also says that, by default a value *V<sub>i</sub>* is observed by the downstream flowable in the same thread *T<sub>i</sub>* as it was emitted.

This means that even if `merge` guarantees that the downstream receives values serially, it might observe them on different threads.

Now here's the question: Does RxJava guarantee that the observation of a value *happens-before* the observation of next value? Basically will all the changes made in memory while observing a value on *T<sub>i</sub>*  be visible while observing the next value on *T<sub>j</sub>*?

Comment: We have to, the spec mandates it: https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#1.3

Comment: Cool, that's what I was looking for. If you could turn that into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Also, as a general comment: That page contains really important information that I wish was present in the Javadocs of the various interfaces. I would never have found that page (and therefore that information) without your link.

Comment: We are an open source project. If you think the documentation could benefit from expanding, please open a pull request.